# Access: display warning if room has no check-out date

Tags: ms-access

We have an Access-db which lists the residents of a carehome. When a resident moves out of the room, there's a field to enter the date of exiting. Sometimes (a lot actually) the user forgets to enter this date.
When registering a new resident to room 1, I'd like to show a warning if the exit date of the former resident is still blank or if the starting date of the new resident overlaps with the one from the previous resident.
Prevention of input optional. Any suggestions?
Tnx!

Comment: You should read up on [Data Macros](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200?ocmsassetid=ha010378170&correlationid=32f72b11-ab0a-490d-84ed-3312c1d598cc&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

Comment: I've never used Data Macros. An alternative is form BeforeUpdate event. Data validation is a common topic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose as noted, the point to fix this would the the form/time/place when the date of exit is not filled out. So, you could in that form simple use the before update event. Check if the exit date is not entered, and thus pop up a message and set cancel = true in the before update event. The user will not be able to exit or save that data until such time they enter that exit date.

Now I suppose in your new booking form, you can simply query/check the database for records that don't have that exit date, and pop up a warning .

```
dim strWhere    as string
strWhere = "(RoomNumber = " & me!RoomNumber & ") AND (EixtDate is null)"

if dcount("*","tblBookings",strWhere) > 0 then
    msgbox "warning - this room has previous bookings without Exit date"
    do whatever you want here!
End if
```